# How to use Dalauney Triangulation to triangulate points(longitude and latitude) on Maps, within a certain radius

Tags: java, triangulation, delaunay, jts

I am working on a  problem where I need to use Dalauney triangulation to extrapolate location points on google Maps. I have tried using JTS but the output I get returned is a single Polygon of 4 points. I am using Polylines to visualize these triangles but it only returns one triangle. I am getting back the location points and feeding them to the algorithm, but it's not working so I tried statically passing them but the result seems to be similar, Even added random noise and increased the tolerance, but I still get back one triangle. Could anyone help me out

```
           `GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
            List<Coordinate> dal = new ArrayList<>();
           // replace (x,y) with location coordinates
            dal.add(new Coordinate(x1,y1));
            dal.add(new Coordinate(x2,y2));
            dal.add(new Coordinate(x3,y3));
            dal.add(new Coordinate(x4,y4));

            DelaunayTriangulationBuilder builder = new DelaunayTriangulationBuilder();
            builder.setSites(dal);
            builder.setTolerance(0.00001);
            Geometry tri = builder.getTriangles(gf);
            System.out.println("Triangulation output: " + tri);
            Random random = new Random();
            
            List<Coordinate> dalWithNoise = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Coordinate c : dal) {
                double noiseLatitude = random.nextDouble() * 0.001;
                double noiseLongitude = random.nextDouble() * 0.001;
                dalWithNoise.add(new Coordinate(c.x + noiseLatitude, c.y + noiseLongitude));
            }
            DelaunayTriangulationBuilder builder = new DelaunayTriangulationBuilder();
                builder.setSites(dal);
                builder.setTolerance(0.000000001);
                Geometry tri= builder.getTriangles(gf);
                builder.toVertices(dalWithNoise);
                if (tri == null) {
                    System.out.println("Error: Triangulation generation failed");
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println("Number of triangles generated: " + tri.getNumGeometries());
                for (int i = 0; i < tri.getNumGeometries(); i++) {
                    Geometry subGeometry = tri.getGeometryN(i);
                    System.out.println("Triangle " + (i + 1) + " vertices: " +               subGeometry.getCoordinates());
                }

                System.out.println("Triangulation output: " + tri);
            for (int i = 0; i < tri.getNumGeometries(); i++) {
                Geometry g = tri.getGeometryN(i);
                Coordinate[] coords = g.getCoordinates();
                for (int j = 0; j < coords.length - 1; j++) {
                    System.out.println("x: " + coords[j].x + ", y: " + coords[j].y);
                }
            }`
```

Comment: What are the values for your coordinates (x1, y1), (x2, y2), etc.?

Comment: They are the location coordinates around my area for eg: ( 40.75672746728996, -73.9854172135305)

Comment: Well, the JTS folks are pretty good, so I was thinking the problem was with your input coordinates rather than the triangulation.  I gather that the locations are sensitive in some regard so you don't want to post them.  That's reasonable enough. So I would suggest you plot them out by hand and inspect them to see if they have a valid geometry.  You could also try running them through the Tinfour library, but if they don't work in JTS, they probably won't work in the other environment.